# Add panoramic view - Added into html file in iphone app

Tags: iphone, html, ios4

I have html file which shows panoramic view of a place.  HTML file calls xml, swf and js files in it.

I try opening that html file in UIWebView, it shows following message : 
"This content requires html5/css3, webgl, or adobe flash player version 9 or higher"

HTML file is in resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to upload the files to server and open the html file into UIWebView as iOS device doesn't support flash or swf files.

Comment: Hosting the .swf on the server won't solve the issue -- the poster will have to find panoramic view code which is js only.

Comment: UIWebView will call html file as source and html file's javascript will call xml and swf files according to the question asked..

Answer (score 2):

You can't play adobe flash (swf) on an iOS device.

Comment: flash is still not supported in uiwebview